# JMeter - Get header value and write in a log file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am doing API REST Performance testing. For each API call, I have to send a unique Transaction and request ID in headers.

I use `${__UUID()}` in headers, and it's working fine.

To track the transaction id in server logs, I want to print that `function( ${__UUID()})` generated value in a log file with API name. For that, I have tried many ways, but those are very complicated and messy. Without adding a preprocessor can we log the value of the transaction id value from the request header?

I would be grateful if you throw some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand why you don't want top use a preprocessor. I think it would be the best solution to generate the uuid in a script and store value before each request execution:

```
import java.util.UUID;
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
log.info("Next uuid "+uuid);
vars.put("uuid",uuid);
```

Use the ${uuid} in your request header.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the generated GUID printed in [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) - just wrap it into [__log() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__log) like:

```
${__log(${__UUID()})}
```

[image]

This will both generate the GUID and print the corresponding line into *jmeter.log* file:

[image]

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)